# UITextView in custom shape

Tags: ios, uitextview

I want make a custom UITextView that can be drawn in to custom shape like can be seen in the image url.

Actually, I can draw the text in to a shape but it's not editable. I came across with NSTextContainer class that people using it by overriding lineFragmentRectForProposedRect method but could not find an example working with complex shapes.

Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJWh8.png

Comment: Is the text going to be static?

Comment: No, it has to be an editable uitextView. It has to fit in to shape while user changing the text.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my demo project with text attributes and Text Kit. It has an example of custom text shape. Just make the UITextView editable. 
https://github.com/rambler-digital-solutions/TextKitPresentation

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks idva, it helped a lot.

Comment: I need demo project. But demo not found in GitHub. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Dipang here is new link https://github.com/idva/typography-ios. But the project needs to be converted to the latest swift

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use a bezier path - something I am not particularly familiar with - however the is documentation on Apple's website : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html